# Searching in SQL server and returning records that match both search criteria but also comparison with other records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I will try to explain you in a simple way what I mean in the title. Let's say that I have a table called [**Persons**] and each record in it is a person, having as columns: 
*Name*, *Surname* and *HashId*.
Now, in my code I am able to search in this table by using as criteria Name and Surname, like for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Persons]
where Name = '..' AND Surname = '..'
```

This will return ALL the records that match the searching criteria. The 3rd column is a computed column that depends on the Name and Surname. So if I search for example someone called "Alex Foo" and in the database there are 2 people with the same name and surname, their HashID will be the same. What I want now is that my query doesn't return those 2 records but only one.. the query has to be able to check whether or not the HashID's are the same and in that case return only 1 record for all those that satisfy this rule. How can my modify my SQL query to reach this purpose? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I omitted an information that now comes clear with your answers. I must filter over the HashId for the following reason: If there are 2 records with the name "Alex" and "alex", their HashId will be the same according to my logic, which is the correct logic for my purposes (the whole code behind is more complex than the explanation I gave you). But a simple select over the name "alex" would return the 2 different records with respectively name "Alex" and "alex". That's why the HashId is important.

Comment: Sample data would help, this is a bit unclear.  If the hash is always the same for name+surname why do you need to *check whether or not the HashID's are the same* if you are searching looking for name+surname?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT name,Surname,HashId ` ? You don't need that `HashId` column to return distinct values

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just group by the name,Surname,HashId?

Like this:

```
SELECT name,Surname,HashId 
FROM [Persons]
where Name = '..' AND Surname = '..'
GROUP BY name,Surname,HashId
```

If all there columns are the same then it will return one row for this

**Edit**

As Panagiotis Kanavos pointed out this will be the same as doing a distinct on the columns too. Maybe this is cleaner. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,Surname,HashId 
FROM [Persons]
where Name = '..' AND Surname = '..'
```

Comment: That's the same as a `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : that is true. I updated the answer